# Append dict items to a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary, and I want to add items of the dictionary type as well...

```
dict = {}
```

I do this:

```
dict['item1'] = { "prop1": "XXX"}
dict['item1'] = { "prop2": "XXX"}
```

Expected result:

```
{"item1" : {"prop1": "XXX", "prop2": "XXX"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `defaultdict` and update the element instead of assigning to it:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
d['item1'].update({"prop1": "XXX"})
d['item1'].update({"prop2": "XXX"})
```